# How to have website think you're visiting from a different country?

Tags: browser, culture, localization

I can test cultures well enough e.g. es-US or fr-CA but the .NET framework has a built in class called System.Globalization.CultureInfo which I believe is returning wrong values as I'm visiting from a US address.

Is there a way to fake the headers or a browser extension that can handle this sort of testing?

I've looked into proxies, but the site is only accessible through VPN.

Comment: Please be careful with localizing.  Years ago I ran into a nasty one--a webmail system that insisted on using my localization and there was no way to override it.  It wasn't my system, though, and I don't speak the language it was set for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the article [how-to-localize-asp-net-controls-based-on-browsers-language-and-culture-settings](http://deepak-sharma.net/2012/01/28/how-to-localize-asp-net-controls-based-on-browsers-language-and-culture-settings/) ?

It is an example of how to use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` when `<%@ Page Language="C#" UICulture="auto" ...` is set.

In Step 6 of the article the autor shows how to simulate different languages in the browser

```
    Step 6:

    Now change language of your browser to Hindi (hi-IN). In Internet Explorer, go to:

    Tools -> Internet Options -> General tab -> Languages -> Add

    Now select Hindi (India) [hi-IN] from the drop down and click OK. 
    Move Hindi to top using Move up button.
```

I donot know if this also work for `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`, too.